# How to check only Alphabet by using preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

How can I compare two sentences the entered in Input text only for alphabet that contains numbers / symbol/ spaces for Duplication??

Example :
lets say a user enter a title name in Input text and stored in the website like this :

> Hello World

and another user want to enter and submit a title name in the website Like this:

> Hello,World

Or

> Hello World,*(':?

What i want to get is to check this string is duplicated or not ? excluding all numbers and symbols?

I have tried this formula , but i didn't get what I want ?

```
$title = preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z0-9]+)/i', '', $title );
```

Comment: So what are you expecting? Some tips: don't use a capturing group if you don't need it. Remove `A-Z` since you're using the `i` modifier `/[^a-z0-9]+/i`

Comment: @HamZa `i` modifier doesn't affect on character classes

Comment: Your regex code works just fine. Can you post your code where you compare thze results?

Comment: @hindmost It does, [here](http://regex101.com/r/hA3fM5)'s a proof

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this should work i tried it. but remove number i.e 0-9 from regex

```
$title = preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z]+)/i', '', $title );

$title2 = preg_replace('/([^a-zA-Z]+)/i', '', $title );
```

then you can compare if two titles are the same by:

```
if ($title ===$title2){  ...   }
```

Comment: A-Z is not needed, you're using the `i` modifier

Answer (score 2):

Try the [levenshtein](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.levenshtein.php) function of PHP. It'll calculate the "distance" between two strings, i.e, the number of characters that'd need to be changed for the strings to become equal.

```
$string_a = "Hello World";
$string_b = "Hello, World!";

echo levenshtein($string_a, $string_b); // 2
```

Comment: didn't worked, I want to compare only Alphabetic character for String which the user typed in input text for submitting as I mentioned if a user enter title name in Input text 
**Ex: " Improving VoD Performance with LAN Client Back-End Buffering"** 

and if the next user Entered same title by following symbols or numbers or spaces 
**EX:"?<(\ Improving VoD Performance with LAN Client Back-End Buffering,;*/?!**

what I want to get is to compare all the title excluding those Symbols or any numbers and spaces ? @i-CONICA

Comment: Then you'd strip those characters first, like all the other responses have addressed. All the other responses address stripping the extra characters, but nobody addressed your comparison. Stripping the extra characters, then doing if($str1 == $str2) isn't very reliable. You'd be best using something like if(levenshtein($str1, $str2) <= 5) (or a percentage of the str_length), to find good matches.

Answer (score 1):

To be unicode compatible, use:

```
$title = preg_replace('/\P{L}+/', '', $title );
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$title = trim(preg_replace('/([^a-z0-9]+)/i', ' ', $title));
```

Comment: Thanks to your answer this worked fine can you explain to me how this works ? if you not mind . @eXi

Comment: `/([^a-z0-9]+)/i` replace all non alphabetic character with a space and `trim` remove all whitespaces from the beginning and end of a string.